# Set document _version via logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Elasticsearch allows you to define an external version in the following manner:

`POST http://localhost:9200/index/type?version=1000&version_type=external`

Is it possible to define a specific version number via the elasticsearch logstash output?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html), you can specify the id, but not the version.  If you specify the id, I believe, it will make a new version.